# Verify if connection exists ( toggling VPN connection)

Tags: node.js, tedious

Im accesing an external db through a VPN and I would like to verify if the connection is healthy before running a query as the VPN connection might have downtimes

Im dealing with two separate .js files: mssql.js

```
var config = require('../config'),
  chalk = require('chalk'),
  mssql = require('mssql');

const poolPromise = new mssql.ConnectionPool(config.mssql)
  .connect()
  .then(pool => {
    console.log('Connected to MSSQL')
    return pool;
  })
  .catch(

    err => {
      console.log('Database Connection Failed! Bad Config: ', err);
      return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        setTimeout(function () {
          resolve("undefined");
        }, 1000)
      })
    }
  )
module.exports = {
  mssql, poolPromise
}
```

and this is called to a function that gets the status here:

```
const { poolPromise } = require('../../../../config/lib/mssql')


exports.getmyServerStatus = function (req, res) {

  poolPromise.then(pool => {
   // console.log("test: ", pool);
    if (pool !== 'undefined') {
      return res.status(200).send({ 'serverStatus': pool.healthy});
    }
    else {
      console.error(chalk.red("Not connected: do something else "));
      return res.status(200).send('{ serverStatus: false }');
    }
  })
};
```

Ive connected to the VPN, server status is true ( works as expected ) 
Ive disconnected from the VPN, the message remains the same ( server status should be false)

Im disconnected from the VPN, server status is false ( works as expected ) 
Im reconnecting to the VPN, server status remains false ( server status should be true)

I've tried all solutions found both here(SO) and on [Tediousjs](https://github.com/tediousjs/node-mssql) , but I do believe that my limited understanding of the pool and promise concepts are preventing me from getting to the desired result.

I also believe that Im not closing the current pool properly, thats why I'm not getting a status change when i toggle with the VPN connection ( connected/disconnected).

Any help/hits are greatly appreciated, though I would like to understand what Im doing wrong here. Thank you for your time

Answer (score 0):

```
if (pool !== 'undefined')
```

That could be the culprit. I think you're trying to check whether the object is `undefined`, in which case, the correct check could is:

```
if (typeof pool !== 'undefined')
if (pool !== undefined)
if (!Boolean(pool))
```

Comment: Thank you for your interest. I've tried them all,but the issue remains. 
I connect to the VPN and  if logic  is executed correctly, but when I close the VPN and access getmyServerStatus again, the prior result remains ( it says that im still connected to the VPN ).

Comment: What happens when you try executing this with vpn off, and then with vpn on? does it "stick" to `false`?